# Why do "checked exceptions", i.e., "value-or-error return values", work well in Rust and Go but not in Java?

Tags: java, language-design, exceptions, go, rust

Java has "checked exceptions", which force the caller of the method to either handle an exception or to rethrow it, e.g.

```
// requires ParseException to be handled or rethrown
int i = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance().parse("42").intValue();
```

Other, more recent languages such as Go and Rust use multiple return values instead:

```
i, err := strconv.Atoi("42")    // Go

match "42".parse::<i32>() {     // Rust
  Ok(n) => do_something_with(n),
  Err(e) => ...,
}
```

The underlying concept is similar: **The caller of the method has to do something about potential errors and can't just let them "bubble up the stack trace" by default** (as would be the case with non-checked exceptions). From some points of view, [checked exceptions can be seen as syntactic sugar for alternative return values.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/614330/87698)

However, [checked exceptions are widely disliked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/613954/87698). The C# designers [made the deliberate decision](https://www.artima.com/intv/handcuffs.html) to not have them. On the other hand, Go and Rust and extremely popular.

---

Why did this concept (see the bolded sentence above) fail in Java but succeed in Go and Rust? What mistakes did the Java designers make that the Go and Rust designers didn't? And what can we learn about programming language design from that?

Comment: Exceptions as an alternative return path and *checked* exceptions that force all callers to *acknowledge* that alternative are separate concepts. As it is, your question mixes up the two issues.

Comment: Java doesn't have union types, so its much harder to do. Without union types, one is forced to create a special return type for each method. Personally, once we have sealed types and primitives over generics I plan do do exactly that in java for my own code, having a `Result` type with `Success` and `Fail` which I'll use for operations that can fail.

Comment: The thing @KilianFoth hints is: the problem with checked exceptions is that they force you to think about each and every error case *right now*. You can not just code the happy path through and then care about the error cases. In Rust or Go, you can just have the application crash in case of an error. No need to add `throws` clauses to all the 10 methods in the call tree - or even worse, write `catch(Throwable ex) {}` which will **not** make the app crash (while a rust panic sure will)

Comment: @marstato if I take the very average programmer, would he really come back to handle all errors cases properly once he wrote down everything ? Note that I generally perform the catch/log/wrap in IllegalStateException thing in lot of cases by default.

Comment: @Walfrat No, i don't either for most code. I write the happy path, test manually and add integration tests. This process makes the most common errors pop up, and then i can add `catch`es where i need them. Luckily, all the code i've worked on so far could tolerate an error in production for how long it would take to add error handling. Never had something break big-time this way that could have been avoided by looking at `throws` clauses during development. The thing is: if you write `catch(ex) {}`, you may not ever notice the error, even though it occurs every second time the code runs.

Comment: @KilianFoth: But that's exactly my point: (a) Checked exceptions and (b) Go/Rust-style return values have one concept in common: The caller of the method has *do something* and can't just let error "bubble up the stack trace" by default. That concept apparently works well in Go/Rust, but not so in Java.

Comment: @KilianFoth: I have rewritten my question to make it more obvious that this is what I meant. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Exceptions aren't alternative return values, they're electrical fuses. They're meant to blow when something that can't be ignored goes wrong. Unfortunately, Java's checked exceptions were created as a way to prevent developers from ignoring such fuses, and ended up making it *harder* to use them

Comment: If you check articles on exception safety you'll see it's *easier* to write exception-safe code if you *don't* use `try/catch`, instead structuring the code so that any state altering operations occur only when the rest of the code succeeded.  Checked exceptions actually make this harder to do.

Comment: [This recently asked question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/420872/96713) is very closely related, particularly in terms of the comparisons presented in some of the answers.

Comment: Are checked exceptions "widely disliked"? Did it "fail" in Java? I didn't read [the link about it being disliked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/613954/87698) in too much detail, but it seems to only mention one or two notable figures and "some developers". And Java seems to still be doing okay, and its popularity would probably come down to many more factors than just this single one. For just about any language feature or syntax (including Go/Rust's way of doing it) you probably can find a few notable figures and some developers who would object to it. I wouldn't read too much into that.

Comment: @BernhardBarker I think a lot of the 'dislike' of checked exceptions in Java came from their overuse in early versions.  This was compounded by the fact that the ability to wrap checked exceptions in unchecked exceptions wasn't added to the JDK until later.  This meant there were a lot of scenarios where errors would get squashed because the developer didn't want to add `throws IOException` or `throws SQLException` to every method declaration in the application.

Comment: `NumberFormatException` is not a checked exception.

Comment: @user207421: Oops, you're absolutely right! Fixed.

Comment: My impression is that Go is even more ridiculed for its error handling than Java’s checked exceptions. So the answer might as well be (in part) ‘no, they don’t’.

Comment: @BernhardBarker Checked exceptions are indeed widely disliked, but much like OOP, only because they're widely misunderstood. Over the last 20 years, I've watched the popular arguments against checked exceptions evolve from ignorance of how they're supposed to be used, to the complaint that they make things harder for compiler writers. Well, yes... shifting cognitive load from developers to the compiler is the whole point of the compiler. I think it's all FUD to justify Microsoft's mistake of not including them in the CLR.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede I'd mostly second that. There are issues with their implementation in Java, some bad examples and some issues. For instance they do clash with the java 8 stream apis and they automatically incur performance costs, that you pay even when you don't need the details (full stacktrace etc.).But I'd also question the widely disliked. At least one of the most popular modern frameworks (SpringBoot) for instance implicitly does encourage their usage in modern microservices. (To a degree I'm not sure makes total sense, but alas). If it were a failed attempt people and framework [cont]

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede designers would avoid them and nobody would miss them. But I rarely see code that just uses RuntimeExceptions ... and it's mostly bad code otherwise (too^^).  They certainly have their issues, but are far from a failed concept. And a good portion of the dreading I think simply stems from the fact that they are the messengers of bad news that one has to deal with.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede I largely agree with what you are saying here but I think part of your argument can be used against checked exceptions: they can increase the cognitive load for developers.  Not so much what to do about them, that's fairly straightforward.  It's when to declare them that's challenging.  There are a lot of subtleties to this and I don't think there's a cut-and-dried answer mainly because it depends on how the code will be used.

Comment: @JimmyJames That's the opposite of my argument. Language support for checked exceptions massively reduces cognitive load. Using them correctly requires a little bit of thinking, but significantly less thinking than writing the same program in a language that doesn't have them, so it's disingenuous to regard the thinking required to use them as an increase. I think the problem is that most developers aren't even aware of the need to think about their handling of unchecked exceptions, or the problems that their failure to do so causes.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede I've spent a lot of time writing Java code but I've also used other languages and I can't say that I every really missed having checked exceptions.  I don't think your assertion bears out in reality.  Most of the time, I find them to be an annoyance if not a hinderance to getting things done.

Comment: @JimmyJames I've also worked with different languages, but I prefer Java and one reason are the checked exceptions. It's a small aspect, but I totally don't see them as a hindrance, rather than an easy signpost that means I have one thing less to worry when Juniors do pieces of work (or I clearly see when they just do a lazy catch and ignore attempt). Yes it feels a bit liberating when you don't need to worry about exceptions - until you start worrying where things might go wrong... But obviously it's also a personal style question.

Comment: @FrankHopkins I'm not sure where you get the idea that you "don't worry about exceptions" when they are unchecked.  Maybe it's the kind of application I usually work with but most of the time, exceptions are simply passed back to a generic handler i.e. they either kill the application or they kill a transaction.  I don't worry about them any less and it doesn't really change the shape of the application in any meaningful way.  I just don't have boilerplate catch, wrap and throw blocks.  I'm not anti-checked exceptions, I just don't see any evidence that they have a real impact on quality.

Comment: @JimmyJames well often enough I don't want to kill the application or transaction just because something went a little weird. Sure, if you compartmentalize well enough it's not a problem but then you have to do it and design it that way and you need to be aware which calls can fail and which don't (unless hell freezes over and then yes, go with the default treatment for that). To me checked exceptions are perfect warning signs of those cases that save me other means to communicate the component design. And they still support the "just throw up" model, you just declare them upwards.

Comment: @JimmyJames so to me there is no annoying boilerplate because I put it where I would have it otherwise too. One thing that could be improved is the actual syntax, try-catch is a bit clunky - that's one thing I would indeed count as improvable implementation of the concept. And sure I'm not saying everyone does not deal with exceptions when they're not checked, but to me it reduces brain power to make those decisions. Like lines in a notebook help to write sometimes, while we all can live without them. but yes, dep. on style they are more or less helpful.

Comment: @JimmyJames and for the springboot (HTTP/REST web services) case mentioned above: while I have some concerns I do love the fact that at a web service endpoint definition I see all major exceptions that could trigger a non-200 response (especially all 4xx responses) and can trace how they can happen by following the declaration flow. Anyway, enough semi-off-topic rambling in the comment section for today ;)

Comment: " I don't want to kill the application or transaction just because something went a little weird." I generally associate this attitude with buggy software: [fail-fast](https://www.martinfowler.com/ieeeSoftware/failFast.pdf)

Comment: To give a little more context: let's say an application's behavior is dependent on some sort of configuration.  If there's an IO exception during an attempt to load that configuration, usually it's best to simply exit and dump the stack.  I've never come across a scenario where continuing in an invalid state was helpful.  A similar scenario is if a transaction runs into an issue with a DB or a web service, regardless of where in the transaction this occurred, the desired result is the same.  There's no value in repeating the same error-handling in multiple places.

Comment: @JimmyJames I used almost nothing but Java for 15 years before moving to C#. I really love C#, but I'm painfully aware of the burden created by the absence of checked exceptions. The majority of bugs that have sneaked into production could never have happened in Java.

Comment: @JimmyJames gosh, it's not the same error handling, that is the point. Localized error handling deals locally with the problem and is totally different than a few levels higher where you you throw away the whole aggregate. Dummy example, say you have one method to retrieve all the information for a SE page. Just because the comments cannot be loaded isn't a good reason to not provide the question and answers, but if all fails you rather show a full-site error. Or a gaming server, just because the operation for one player fails, isn't a good reason to crash the server for everyone.

Comment: @JimmyJames the big argument of fail fast is basically against swallowing problems, which I agree is a problem if you do it silently. But just crashing your application visibly in the face of your customer is not the best idea. Sure, make errors visible, but keep them local by failing the relevant part or using an error reporting system and you get your direct bug reports along with a customer that can still use the part that works.

Comment: @JimmyJames for the configuration reading example I'm with you though, it's a nice fail fast example because it can be spotted immediately when the software boots up and there is no failsafe recovery or piece that would work safely without it. For database transactions, sure failing the transaction should be one consequence, but there might be others once the transaction failed in-between that and failing the whole operation the transaction was a part of (or even crashing the whole application). checked exceptions don't force you to do something local,they just make you aware that you could.

Comment: @FrankHopkins The kind of things I see are: something goes wrong and the application tries to continue and corrupts data. If you can't pull some data, do you add up the wrong sum and show the user?  Or we might have a situation where a sensor fails on an airplane and instead of shutting down and flipping the controls to the pilot, the computer noses the plane into the sea. I'm not saying that this there is a simple one-size-fits-all solution but it's rare, in my experience, for the immediate code around the exception point to be the right place to handle it.

Comment: @FrankHopkins What I like about checked exceptions is that they notify developers of *some* of the things they need to consider something but the reality is that there are a huge number of unchecked exceptions that could occur at any point in a Java application.  You still need a strategy for handling those anyway.  I think checked exceptions are a good idea that hasn't been fully realized.

Comment: @JimmyJames the distinction you make is important, imho checked exceptions are exactly for those cases where there is a good enough chance that you want specific local handling rather than for cases where you cannot do anything anyway. Sometimes that decision is a bit tricky to make generically. But in some of the places I work I see that quite regular. A lot of remote calls to third party systems fall into the category cool if it works, otherwise I want to explicitly only affect that part or translate the generic remote call exception into some generic error response upstream.

Comment: @FrankHopkins I agree on those points. Now that I think about it for a moment, my main criticism of checked exceptions are that they don't play well with abstractions.  An abstract interface has to declare them for implementation to be able to throw them but the interface should not be concerned with implementation details such as what might go wrong.  So in practice, they end up getting wrapped (OK) or squashed (bad).

Comment: @JimmyJames hmm, yes, introducing a particular exception because one implementation might throw it - bad; declaring one on the abstract layer in abstract terms because the operation on that level can run into issues -> good; e.g. a shop interface might throw a NotEnoughMoneyEx. Obviously one could design it differently too, but I would feel this is a valid design. Though the other side of that coin is also overusage of interfaces. A couple years ago interfaces were everywhere - often just to allow tests to work. Nowadays testing frameworks and also software design (microservices) seem to

Comment: @JimmyJames support tests way better (at least in my field), that this isn't a driving factor anymore and interfaces are more reserved to where you actually need/want an interface. Thus less issues in that regard.

Comment: @FrankHopkins Interfaces aren't just about testing.  AS a concrete example: if I am working with a library that requires a Map and want to read from a network resource in the `get` method, there's basically no way around wrapping checked exceptions.

Comment: @JimmyJames I know that they are not just for testing. I'm just saying they often got used just to support testing without other needs and this happens less now such that such conflicts might become less, at least on my end that's what I observe. Anyway, nice discussion, but from my end, we've turned this enough into a forum. Have a nice day, see you at another question perhaps.

Answer (score 44):

> From a scientific point of view, checked exceptions can be seen as alternative return values, e.g.

Exactly. They can be seen that way, and they should be *but they aren't*.

Using an `Error` type like is common in Rust, Elm, Haskell, and in some sub-communities in Scala or a special error value as in Go *is* just an alternative return value indicated in the type system. A checked exception is *like* an alternative return value, but it doesn't use the normal way of returning values, it is a *completely separate*, very different way of "returning values". It also sits outside of the type system, and bolts on a completely separate "checked exception" system onto the type system.

But most importantly, it is not *just* an alternative return value, it is *also* an alternative *control flow*.

Another problem with the *specific* way checked exceptions are implemented in Java, is that they are anti-modular. That is, however, not a fundamental problem of checked exceptions, unlike the ones I mentioned above. There is an idea of *Modular Anchored Exceptions*, for example, where you can specify something like

```java
int foo() throws like bar { return bar(); }
```

And you don't have to know (and leak!) which precise exceptions `bar` can throw. You can even do something like `throws like bar except ArrayOutOfBoundsException` when you are handling some errors yourself.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what this bring, you can just wrap exception in Java. I mean if bar API's change and add one type of checked exception, you don't need to modify the intermediate calls OK, but you still need to deal with the new exception at some point (unless being wrapped already). Also when Java was made, we weren't yet to the point of having module included in languages features. At least not i the mainstreams ones.

Comment: From an electrical engineering point of view, exceptions aren't alternative return types, they're fuses that blow when something goes wrong. A fuse should never be used as either a switch or an indicator. When an HTTP call is made, a 404 shouldn't result in an exception, it's an error result. The application can handle it. A DNS error though is a real problem. The application can't ignore this

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Whether a DNS error is a "real problem" depends upon what one is seeking to do.  If one is trying to determine whether network connectivity has become available after a disruption, a DNS failure may be an expected result.

Comment: A fundamental problem with the design of checked exceptions in Java is that there is no convenient mechanism for distinguishing between exceptions which occurred in situations where the caller was prepared for the consequent disruption in program flow, versus those which occur at times a caller was not thus prepared.  Instead, if a function is defined as throwing `WoozleException`, Java will by default treat *all* function calls it makes as though they may safely propagate a `WoozleException` without recording anything about the resulting disruption in program flow.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: that really depends on the language's culture. For example, languages like Python uses Exceptions liberally and don't necessarily see them as indicating problems. It's just an alternative control structure when you just need to go up and unwind the call stack. In fact everytime you make a loop, Python internally will throw StopIteration exception. Exceptions are also generally safer than status code to avoid "time of check to time of use" race condition.

Comment: @LieRyan it depends on the domain more than the language. Some things require fuses, some require indicator lights only. Saying one or the other is bad doesn't help - except for the unchecked status codes returned by C/C++ code. Not that lazy programmers can't short-circuit every check. Every time I see a discussion of Exceptions vs return values I remember the [Fuse Replacement guide](https://external-preview.redd.it/hMyKCqho5V2kdvWONIltMBwbE4nh7Y5zUFfZs5FhSjk.jpg?auto=webp&s=e6317d7441f5fbc35c893cadb39bf99f39914ad0)

Comment: @supercat I'm confused what the distinction there is, and what the alternative would be. If a `WoozleException` is thrown, control needs to pass _somewhere_; if the programmer doesn't specify where, either the compiler can reject the program, or the runtime can abort it, whether the calling code is "prepared" for that or not.

Comment: @IMSoP: IMHO, languages with catch statements should distinguish between exceptions that were thrown in contexts expected by the immediate called function, and those that weren't, and provide a convenient syntax to indicate when a function is expecting that nested functions might throw exceptions.  Languages should also provide `finally` blocks with an easy way of knowing whether they are being invoked because the main block is completing normally or is exiting via exception.

Comment: @supercat I'm still not sure what you're expecting the language to do differently for an "expected" vs "unexpected" exception. And isn't "provide a syntax to indicate nested functions might throw exceptions" exactly what Java's `throws` keyword does? The `finally` enhancement sounds sort-of useful, but I'm not sure how different it would be from catching an exception and then re-throwing it unchanged.

Comment: @IMSoP: The problem with the `throws` keyword is that there is no means of distinguishing parts of a function where nested calls are expected to throw an exception that should be propagated, versus those that aren't.  I forgot to mention the most important part of the `finally` enhancement, which is that "try with resources" (Java) or `using`/`IDisposable` should let the cleanup function know what's going on.  If one e.g. wraps a transaction with one of those constructs and code leaves the block "normally" without performing either "commit" or "rollback", that should trigger an exception...

Comment: ...because of the improper usage, or else auto-commit (the latter could be a useful default *for when the block exits normally*, but if code exited the block because of an exception, that shouldn't commit any transaction that was in progress nor stifle the exception that caused the block to exit.  Java is a bit better than .NET in that even if the cleanup throws a "transaction not committed" exception, the try-with-resources mechanism would preserve the original exception if code knows to look for it, but it still provides no way for a transaction wrapper to auto-commit only for normal exit.

Comment: It would be more useful, in Java, to have a mechanism to transform every exception thrown by a function into a single checked exception. Something like: `void foo() throws IOException, LibException or LibInternalErrException` that would wrap the function in a `try/catch` that will call the constructor of `LibInternalErrException` if the thrown exception is not `IOException` or `LibException` or `LibInternalErrException`. `LibInternalErrException` must be checked and the original exception, along with the function parameters, would be passed to its constructor. ...

Comment: ... One may think about a way to pass some context to the constructor of `LibInternalErrException` but at that point maybe it's better to simply write one or more handler for `Exception`, convert and throw.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos [C++17 `[[nodiscard]]` is your friend.](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/nodiscard)

Answer (score 27):

*Disclaimer: This will, to a degree, be my own personal take on the problem. I love programming language design, I've thought, read, and discussed a lot of about PL design in general, and the hard topic of errors in particular. This gives me some experience, and also an appreciation that beyond objective factors, there is a lot of subjectivity at play. I will try to separate objective from subjective, but I am biased and therefore may err.*

**TL;DR: Checked Exceptions are poorly integrated in Java.**

---

> However, [checked exceptions are widely disliked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613954/the-case-against-checked-exceptions). The C# designers made the deliberate decision to not have them.

Be careful about generalizations.

The *current incarnation* of Checked Exceptions in Java is widely disliked. The reason for the dislike, however, may be either Checked Exceptions themselves, OR the current incarnation in Java. And possibly a mix of both.

---

**Poor integration**

As a simple example, look at the interface of [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html): if you want to use `filter`, or `map`, your predicates cannot throw a Checked Exception.

The underlying issue here is that the Java language offers no way to easily handle, and manipulate, lists of Checked Exceptions in a generic context. At the end of the day, I'd like to be able to write:

```
class Foo<T>
{
    <R, ME..., FE...> R transform(
        Function<? extends T, ? extends R, throws ME...> mapper,
        Predicate<? extends R, throws FE...> filter
    )
        throws (ME..., FE..., -BarException)
    {
        try
        {
             return filter(mapper(this.element));
        }
        catch (BarException e)
        {
             return default();
        }
    }
}
```

And I *can't*.

Due to the rise of Generics, and of Functional Programming idioms such as `Stream`, Checked Exceptions have become increasingly more inconvenient as time passes.

---

**Exceptions**

We could stop at poor integration and call it a day, concluding that Checked Exceptions in and out of themselves are perfectly fine, and Java just botched it.

A closer look, however, reveals that Exceptions themselves are part of the issue in the first place. Specifically, the main problem of exceptions is that they are not return types.

One of the advantage that Rust or Haskell have in using Return Types to signal Errors is that any advance that allows better compile-time manipulation of the Return Types (meta-programming) simultaneously grants better compile-time manipulation of Error Specifications in function signatures.

On the other hand, using Exceptions means that efforts must be, to a degree, duplicated between meta-programming on Return Types and meta-programming on Exception Specifications.

This comes to a head in Java because Java doesn't support Variadic Generics, but supports Variadic Exception Specifications. It makes it even more complicated to provide proper meta-programming facilities for the Exception Specifications... and is likely the root cause of Java designers having seemingly thrown their hands up.

A language *could* choose to provide proper meta-programming facilities to manipulate Exception Specifications in signature, and in that case Checked Exceptions *would* feel first class. Yet, even then, I expect that it would still not be as convenient as manipulating Return Types, because you would then need to manipulate *both* Return Types and Exception Specifications, leading to extra work -- as demonstrated in computation of `noexcept` clauses in C++.

---

**Conclusion**

The rise of Generics -- notably for Functional Programming -- has led to a rise of Meta Programming which requires manipulating function signatures at compile-time.

Exception Specifications are not as convenient to manipulate in function signatures -- at best they double the work, as Return Types must always be manipulated regardless -- and may not support manipulation at all as it requires extra-work on the part of language designers and language implementers.

Checked Exceptions in Java require Exception Specifications in a language which does not allow manipulating them via meta-programming, making their use awkward to impossible in Generic code, which is increasingly prevalent.

By comparison, Rust's `Result` type benefits from all the meta-programming machinery available in Rust in general -- without extra expense from designers, implementers, or users -- and therefore offers a much smoother experience.

Comment: Also, the number of cases that demanded handling exceptions that could not occur. No, StreamReader.close(); isn't going to throw IOException. And the case of getting the UTF-8 character encoder. And too many more.

Answer (score 12):

Checked exceptions can't be treated as just another part of the expression. They must be handled out of line.

With an error return value, you can write a function that converts error values to a default value, for example. Something like this (even if the variant type has no `getOrDefault` method):

```
setNumber(getOrDefault(parseInt(stringValue), 0));
```

With checked exceptions, you have to write this:

```
int parsedNumber;
try {
    parsedNumber = parseInt(stringValue);
} catch(NumberFormatException exc) {
    parsedNumber = 0;
}
setNumber(parsedNumber);
```

which is much less wieldy *and* you can't abstract it. Sure, you could write a `parseIntOrDefault` function, but you'd also have to write a separate `parseLongOrDefault`, `parseFloatOrDefault`, etc. There's no way to write a general "convert parse error to default value" function.

And no, you can't put `setNumber` inside the `try` block, because what if `setNumber` can also throw a NumberFormatException?

Comment: "...and you can't abstract it": I haven't written Java for a while, but in C# I *could* abstract that using a method that takes a lambda (e.g. `private T getOrDefault<T>(Func<T> operationThatCanThrow, T defaultValue)`. Are you sure that isn't possible in Java?

Comment: @Heinzi You also have to write a `Func<T>` interface that can throw a NumberFormatException, and you have to accept that every call will allocate an object on the heap, which is an immediate no-go if you're worried about performance...

Comment: Also, prior to Java 8 (and yes, such versions still matter sometimes) the syntax for doing it was about as unwieldy as just writing the try block.

Comment: Makes sense. I only asked out of curiosity.

Comment: @user253751: Seems like the real problem here is a lack of first class function support, not checked exceptions. With first class function support (and some level of generics), you could write a function like similar to `getOrDefault` that accepted the function to call and the arguments to call it with, along with the default on error, which would then use code similar to your second block (but catching `java.lang.Exception` to handle arbitrary exceptions). This is doable with exceptions in both C++ (via templates) and Python (via dynamic typing), neither of which have checked exceptions.

Comment: I think part of the problem with your answer is you're ignoring that the OP considers the value-or-error return type equivalent to checked exceptions (where any exception must be handled or explicitly declared as part of the function prototype). Your comparison of value-or-error to checked explains why Rust/Go are better than Java, but not why *checked* exceptions (unpopular) specifically are bad/worse than unchecked exceptions (not nearly as unpopular).

Comment: @ShadowRanger To your first point: the "some level of generics" is exactly the problem here, because `throws` clauses need a whole extra set of meta-programming features to support such cases, and can't get them "for free" by being part of the main type system; [a different answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/420949/96713) makes that point more clearly. To your second point: the question didn't ask about unchecked exceptions (or whatever the equivalent would be with union types - automatically unwrapped monads of some sort, perhaps) so why should answers have to cover them?

Comment: @ShadowRanger Not having first-class functions is a side effect of the [Kingdom of Nouns](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2006/03/execution-in-kingdom-of-nouns.html).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Unchecked exceptions in Java are things you usually don't handle. Think ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. There is no unwieldy catch code because you don't catch them. But Enum.valueOf (which throws an unchecked exception on failure) is just as bad as Integer.parseInt (which throws a checked one)

Comment: @Heinzi The other problem with your getOrDefault is that a good default doesn't always exist.  If I'm writing code that gets an integer from a JSON blob, any integer might be valid and using a default if they don't have one can lead to major bugs.  To the point I consider those functions almost code smells, they provide convenience but are easily misused.

Comment: @user253751 actually, [`Integer.parseInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) throws a [`NumberFormatException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html), which is a [`RuntimeException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) and therefore unchecked. I stumbled over that a few times (it should have been a checked one, but isn't, and cannot be changed anymore without breaking backwards compatibility).

Comment: @user253751 but there are also some people arguing that the decision was correct - the parameter is expected to be validated before the call, and if called with an unparsable `String` parameter the method is justified to raise a subclass of `IllegalArgumentException`, as this is a breach of contract and thus a programming error. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205624/why-numberformatexception-is-runtime. It is basically a bit of a mess, because these parts of the contract cannot (or at least are not) be properly expressed through the type system.

Comment: @Hulk How does one validate that a string is parsable? Oh, right, by trying to parse it...

Answer (score 8):

There are three parts to error code:

1. Code that generates the errors.
2. Code that handles the errors.
3. Code that just propagates the errors from part 1 to part 2.

Most programmers don't give part 3 much thought, because most "enterprise" languages use unchecked exceptions where the part 3 code is essentially invisible. In error propagating code, you want to be aware that there are errors potentially propagating through your code, because *someone* in the call stack above you is going to have to handle those errors.

However, the propagating code doesn't care what those errors are. When new kinds of errors get thrown, or some kinds of errors start being handled further down in the stack, you don't care. You just pass along whatever you get.

The problem with checked exceptions is they force you to care. If I want to start throwing a checked exception, I have to change the type signature of every single propagating function, breaking compatibility. Some of those functions might be in code I have no control over.

In SOLID terms, you're breaking the open-closed principle in a big way, because you can't add a new function at the bottom of the stack without modifying all the propagating functions in the middle.

Go and Rust force you to know the potential for an error exists, but if you are just propagating the error, you don't have to precisely know every potential value it might take.

Comment: Sure you do! If they change `int Integer.parseInt(String) throws NumberFormatException` to `int Integer.parseInt(String) throws NumberFormatException, IDontFeelLikeItException` then you have to update the callers. But if they change `Variant<int, NumberFormatError>` to `Variant<int, NumberFormatError, IDontFeelLikeItError>` you have the exact same problem!

Comment: The whole idea of **both** checked exceptions and using sum types to indicate errors is that changing the possible errors is an *interface* change. And throwing a new type of error **IS** an interface change; you can't call the code in the same context that isn't prepared to handle the new error (it only seems that way if you're using a catch all handler, because it's already prepared to handle everything). You *can* add a function at the bottom of the call stack if you handle the new error (say by wrapping it into an error type that the calling context already knows how to handle).

Comment: Yes, but it depends how you make the interface. You can make a type that is extensible at the "throw" side and "catch" side without needing to change the interface at the "propagate" side.

Comment: I'm not sure it's true that it's easier to propagate a union type / multiple return than an exception: if you call a function that returns `[error, result]` and want to propagate `error` rather than handling it, you need to return `[error, result]` in turn. If you simply assume that _all_ functions return an untyped `error` as part of their signature, that's the same as checked exceptions with everything marked `throws Throwable`; you're working around the issue, not handling it.

Comment: "The problem with checked exceptions is they force you to care." I think that's a misunderstanding. The list of possible exceptions is part of the public API (checked or not). It follows that if your implementation code throws any other exception, you must wrap it (again, checked or not). That way new checked exceptions can be cleanly handled.

Comment: The more I re-read this and other people's comments, the more convinced I am that the difference you're observing is to do with the type hierarchy of the errors, not whether they're thrown or returned. It may be true that Java code tends to use more specific error types than Go code, and that may even contribute to how users feel about interacting with them, but that's a completely orthogonal design decision to whether to signal them with union types, multiple return values, or exception throwing.

Comment: @IMSoP It may also be that Rust/Go deduce the type of the error, so the propagating code doesn't have to change to handle the type change

Comment: @Caleth If the compiler can deduce the fact that a function propagates errors _at all_, that's equivalent to unchecked exceptions: ignore the errors, and let them bubble up if they happen. If the compiler can only deduce _which subtype of the declared error_ is being returned/thrown, you're back to declaring a very broad error type on every function. Calling code can't rely on this deduced sub-type anyway, because a change to the called function will change it; so in practice, you have to _catch_ the broad error type as well, and we're back where we started.

Comment: @IMSoP I mean if `Value | ErrorA source()` passes through `OtherValue | ErrorA intermediate()` on it's way to `void destination()`, a change to `Value | ErrorB source()` doesn't matter if the exact type is never uttered

Comment: @Caleth But it _does_ matter, because the code in `destination()` needs to know which errors to handle, and that code is written by a human, not the compiler. You might not have to edit the source code for `intermediate()`, but its contract has still changed, and everything that calls it needs to change in response. If `destination` is written on the assumption that `intermediate` might give any error at all, it's fine; if it's written on the previously-correct assumption that `intermediate` will only give `ErrorA`, it's now broken.

Comment: @IMSoP that's what this answer says. The code in the middle doesn't change, just where the error occurs and where it is handled

Comment: @Caleth Right, but that still has nothing to do with checked exceptions versus union types, it's just the compiler letting the developer be lazy and leave bits out of their source code. You still need to know the actual signature to write correct code, and it's still a breaking change if you change that signature _anywhere in the stack. The only way for it not to be a breaking change is not to sub-type the errors at all.

Comment: @IMSoP it's a difference between Go/Rust and Java. And abstracting away a type is isn't being lazy.

Comment: @Caleth Feel free to post an answer explaining that there are other differences between the languages than exceptions vs union types, and that these differences contribute more to their reception. This answer does not do so, it attributes things to checked exceptions which are actually independent design decisions. I think we're also getting in a muddle between _meta-programming_ (templated/generic signatures) and _implicit typing_ (signatures that have more information in the compiled version than the source code), but that's drifting a long way from this answer.

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt I mostly agree with this but I have to take exception (pun intended) with this: "I have to change the type signature of every single propagating function, breaking compatibility" This was essentially what was often done back in the say early aughts but it was never strictly necessary and it's not something you would see in contemporary Java from competent developers.  A checked exception can be wrapped in an unchecked exception as a cause.  Not that what you are describing never happens but it's something that I would call out as an issue in a review.

Answer (score 7):

There are some good points made in other answers, but I feel each picks out a different aspect, so I'm going to try to bring them together.

### Checked vs unchecked errors

The idea of statically checking code is to make "bad" programs impossible to write. In other words, it places *constraints* on what the programmer can do. Those constraints have a natural tendency to conflict with the programmer's main goal: to efficiently express a desired behaviour.

Language designers can do two things to make this less "painful" for the programmer:

- Relax the constraints in certain situations, e.g. allowing some categories of errors to go unchecked
- Provide expressive abstractions which work well alongside the constraints, e.g. short-hand syntaxes for passing an error up the stack

Whether a particular language provides a "good" set of compromises and abstractions is a matter of opinion.

### Returning vs throwing

Exceptions are theoretically equivalent to additional return values only in the same sense that a foreach loop is theoretically equivalent to a while loop: they provide a different developer experience.

The primary difference is that exceptions introduce an additional *control flow* to the program - after a "throw" statement, control automatically jumps to the appropriate "catch" block, rather than the context the subroutine was called from.

This makes some things easier to express, such as a sequence of dependent statements, or elements within an expression, where you want to abort the sequence or expression as soon as any error is encountered, e.g.:

```
try {
   doSomething( 
       convertToUpperCase(functionThatMightError()),
       anotherFunctionThatMightError() + someOtherValue
   );
} catch(error foo) {
   doSomethingElse();
}
```

However, it makes other things more difficult to express, such as substituting a default value into an expression in case of error:

```
foo = functionThatMightError() -> ifErrorThen(fallbackValue);
```

Because exceptions *always* cause a jump in control, there has to be a separate statement to jump to:

```
try {
   foo = functionThatMightError();
} catch(error e) {
   foo = fallbackValue;
}
```

It would be possible for a language to help the programmer express this, with some kind of inline catch which meant control didn't jump; as far as I know, Java does not. It is also possible for languages *without* exceptions to help the programmer express the "abort-on-error" case, e.g. [Haskell's do notation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_notation).

### Checked exceptions vs static types

Because throwing and returning are not interchangeable, checked exceptions need to track extra information for each function: rather than `{ input types, return type }` the signature now includes `{ input types, return type, possible exceptions }`. Tools the language provides to do expressive things with `return type` don't automatically apply to `possible exceptions`.

For instance, for the function `map( someList, someTransform )`, the language might provide tools to specify that the return type of `map` is related to the type of `someTransform`:

```
map( List<T> someList, Transform<T,U> someTransform ): List<U>
```

With checked exceptions, the language now *also* needs to allow the programmer to express how the *possible exceptions* thrown by `map` relate to those thrown from `someTransform`.

If the language *does* provide a syntax to express this, the programmer now needs to understand and apply it.

### Checked exceptions in Java specifically

Some of the common complaints about checked exceptions in Java are the result of design decisions or common practices in that language.

For instance:

- The original standard library in Java used checked exceptions heavily, where it might have been more useful to mix it with other types of error handling.
- Exceptions in Java tend to be of very specific types, leading to long names, and long lists of possible cases in in `throws` clauses. Some more recent languages make less use of sub-typing for their errors (whether thrown or returned).
- Java does support leaving some exceptions unchecked, but this is baked into the single-inheritance type hierarchy, rather than on a per-class or even per-instance basis.
- Java exceptions always capture a stack trace, which is relatively expensive, and not necessary if the error is handled immediately. This is a common design for exceptions, but not actually inevitable.

Answer (score 5):

> checked exceptions can be seen as syntactic sugar for alternative return values

This is the modern perspective on this language feature, but the feature was initially intended and used for a different purpose, at which it failed.

Checked exceptions were added to the Java language before its initial release back in 1996. Back then, Java aspired to be a more dynamic and robust C++. Back then, exception support in C++ was rather new and controversial, but the Java designers felt that exceptions were more robust than returning error codes (because it is harder to accidentally ignore an exception that an error code), and made exceptions an integral part of the language. However, since C++ exception support was so new, some aspects of its exception support were still rather experimental at the time, and one such aspect were "exception specifications". Since the Java team could not wait, they opted to finish were that was going, and invented checked exceptions.

And so they had a new tool that they felt revolutionized error handling in software, and used it liberally when writing the first version of the Java API, communicating nearly all error conditions using checked exceptions - and since Java aspired to be a robust language, they were unusually diligent in communicating possible error conditions.

Together, this meant that not only the Java API was fussy about exceptions, but it also forced this onto its callers. For instance, when you do `monitor.wait()` you have to handle a checked `InterruptedException`, even when you know that nobody is interrupting threads. Or when you do `new InputStreamReader(file, "ascii")`, you have to handle an `UnsupportedEncodingException`, even though ASCII is guaranteed to be supported by the Java spec.

That is, the early Java API overused checked exceptions to communicate error conditions that callers often don't care about.

The pain of this is still felt today because there is no way to remove a checked exception from a throws clause without changing calling code or making the exception type unchecked by changing its class hierarchy, which is often impossible because this single hierarchy is the only way to catch a group of exception types.

That is, the major pain point of checked exceptions is not that checked exceptions are supported, but their overuse by the Java API, which can not be corrected without breaking API compatibility.

But even if that weren't the case, returning union types is strictly superior to checked exceptions for the following reasons:

- checked exceptions are *exceptions*. For instance, their construction captures a stack trace, which is quite expensive (you can suppress this if all super classes collaborate to use the 4 argument constructor of `Throwable`, but doing so might surprise your callers ...)
- the decision whether the exception is checked depends on the class hierarchy. This means you can't throw the same exception checked from one method, but unchecked from another. It also means that callers can't catch related exceptions of different checkedness as a group.
- since exceptions are classes they need globally unique names, which tend to be longer than method-specific ones (compare `NoSuchElementException` to `none`). Also, classes take more effort to declare.
- exceptions don't play nice with scoping rules, making their use quite verbose. For instance, we have to write:

  ```
  ReallyLongType<With, Many, Generics> result;
  try {
      result = foo();
  } catch (ReallyLongTypeCurrentlyNotAvailableException e) {
      result = defaultValue;
  }

  result.bar();
  ```

  rather than:

  ```
  var result = foo() or defaultValue;
  ```

And that's why, in modern java code, we often prefer union types over checked exceptions. For instance, the above can be written as

```
    var result = foo().orElse(defaultValue);
```

if `foo` returns an `Optional`.

**And what can we learn about programming language design from that?**

- be mindful of the different maturity levels of different language features, and have a process for incubating new language features that allows you to undo mistakes and extensively test the new feature in real world use cases before committing to its perpetual support (I think TC39, which evolves EcmaScript, [does this really well](https://tc39.es/process-document/)).
- that some error codes can be replaced by exceptions does not imply that all error codes should be.

Comment: As with a lot of answers here, this doesn't make clear which differences are between _checked exceptions and union types_, in general; and which are between _Java and other languages_, or _Java's implementation of checked exceptions and other possible implementations_. In particular, the phrase "returning union types is strictly superior to checked exceptions" sounds like a universal truth, but most of the bullet points following it are actually implementation details of Java that another language could easily avoid.

Comment: Also, regarding naming, you say "compare `NoSuchElementException` to `none`" but give no evidence that that's a fair comparison. "none" looks suspiciously like the name of a _value_, not a _type_, but what type is it a value of? `ElementResolverResult` perhaps? Java is certainly notorious for its long-winded type names, but I think that's as much cultural as anything else.

Comment: The question already says that checked exceptions are conceptually equivalent to union types. OP already knows there is no difference, so why should I restate that fact?

Comment: As for NoSuchElementException, my answer does give a reason: A name that must be globally unique tends to be longer than one that is only locally unique. The larger the scope, the longer the names ...

Comment: To the first comment: I didn't say that comparing Java to other languages was a bad approach to the question; I suggested that you could be clearer that that's what you're doing, rather than making statements that seem to be comparing the _concepts_, like the one I quoted. To the second comment: what is the context where "none" is a local name, but otherwise equivalent to "NoSuchElementException"?

Comment: In theory the purpose of InterruptedException is to evaluate whether to stop or retry even though personally I never put a counter to decide whether the thread was interrupted too many times.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: It is too easy to just "*try catch swallow*" everything in java`*`. Where in Rust and Go, it's much easier to just write good error control code 'correctly', and make it hard to do poorly. i.e., "Falling into the pit of success" programming paradigm.

I strongly suggest you read Joe Duffy's [blog on error handling strategies](http://joeduffyblog.com/2016/02/07/the-error-model/), which were looked at while developing the Midori OS

---

`*` Perhaps since java is a common University language, this "*try catch swallow*" 'strategy, is a bad habit picked up as a student; whose biggest problem was just getting the code to compile, then maybe actually putting out the correct output. Maintainability and code quality were not their biggest concerns.

Comment: Thanks for the blog link, that was the most interesting thing I've read in a while!

Comment: @Heinzi I found almost all of Joe Duffy's bog posts fascinating. I am very sad that Midori OS didn't get developed further. It will be interesting to see what MS does with their extended version of rust they are planning on using for Windows.

Answer (score -1):

The problem with using always the return value approach is that often the developers end up mixing business logic and error handling.
Beyond return values, error handling could be about:

1. Resource handling, closing access to files or database connections, even though this point was later addressed with the construct try/with resource
2. Transaction handling. When multiple services and databases are involved rolling back a transaction might not be straightforward.
3. Detailed logging. sending messages to external audit systems, bug reports.
4. Rather than an external audit system there might be a full separate error handling platform notified by messages sent in the catch block.
5. Eventual retry. The exception might have been caused by a temporary condition like a timeout or a missing network.

Many of those points were specific to enterprise environments, developers of desktop application might simply complain about the restrictions without thinking about it. But Java is designed for a quite different environment.

Comment: This feels like it's answering a different question.

Comment: @IMSoP I explained a little bit better et the top.

Comment: But the question didn't ask about the _problems_ of return values for error handling; it asked why they are perceived as _better_ than exceptions. Is your intent to challenge the premise of the question by presenting the contrary case?

Comment: @IMSoP The question contain the statement "However, checked exceptions are widely disliked." to that statement I would add "by those who do not understand exception handling". Answering the question literally would mean add BS to BS.

Answer (score -2):

### Awkward typing

The type winds up being `T` with a type union of `A`, `B`, `C`.

This is an odd type that doesn't work best with other things, for example

### Generics

There isn't a good way to do a generic with variadic check exception.

### Classes

In Java, every exception must extend Throwable with a stack trace.

---

You could invent solutions to these, and you'd likely wind up with something pretty close to Go/Rust.

Comment: I have no idea what the first paragraph of this answer means. The type of what? What are A, B and C? What's "odd" about it? What "other things" does it not work with?

Comment: Do you mean the typing of thrown exceptions (when a method throws multiple ones) is awkward? If so, I'm not quite following your argument. Why do you need to do a union at all? Methods in Java can be declared to throw exceptions of different types, or they can just be declared to throw the generic Exception class if you really want (which isn't good practice in Java, but more closely match what happens in Go, so that doesn't seem to be an reason why exception handing in Go "works better").

Comment: "every exception must extend Throwable with a stack trace" - Yes, exceptions must directly or indirectly extend Throwable, but that's just stating how things work in Java. Why do you consider this to be a problem?

Comment: The construction of a Throwable usually involves capturing a stack trace, which is an expensive operation which is likely unnecessary if the caller can gracefully recover from the error.